# Attributed string loses attachment in pasteboard paste

Tags: attachment, nspasteboard

I've spent quite a few days searching for a solution to putting an attributed string with attachment onto an NSPasteboard.

I can read an RTFD file with attachments, modify its text and attributes and then stick it on an NSPasteboard for use in other applications (Mail.app, for example) and that works fine. But what I'd like to do is also add an image at some point in the text. I can do that with text as attributed strings, but if I try inserting an image (as an attachment to an attributed string), the image never arrives (though the rest does).

It seems that RTFD comes in various flavors, and the one I think I need is serialized. I've tried many variations of NSPasteboard declared types, even using FileWrappers, but must be missing something important. No matter what I do, the attachment never seems to arrive.

The strange thing is, if I read an RTFD file that has image attachments, modify it and stick it in a pasteBoard, those original attachments work fine - if I try to add new attachments, they don't make it.  An example is reading an RTFD file, working on it, loading pasteboard, and pasting the results into mail. All the original text and images, plus any new modified or added text and attributes show up, but an attached images is simply missing.

Here's some example code:

Make an attributed string with some text, then add an attached image, then a bit more text, display it in a textView (all that works), then load pasteboard and paste to textEdit or Mail... the attached image isn't there, though the rest is:

```
// get the image
NSImage *myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:  [window dataWithPDFInsideRect:[theImage frame]]];

// set the image as an attachment
NSTextAttachment     *myAttachment  = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
NSTextAttachmentCell *myAttachmentCell = [[NSTextAttachmentCell alloc] initImageCell:myImage];
[myAttachment setAttachmentCell:myAttachmentCell];

// put image inside attributed string
NSAttributedString *myImageString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:myAttachment] ;


// make an attributes dictionary (simply makes text blue) as an example
NSDictionary *myAttributesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSColor blueColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                 nil];

// and add some beginning text
NSMutableAttributedString *theCombinedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Here's an image we just grabbed: \n\n"]  attributes:myAttributesDict];


// now append our attached image 
[theCombinedString appendAttributedString:myImageString];


// and add some following text as an example
NSMutableAttributedString *endString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n How about that!\n"]  attributes:myAttributesDict];


// and stick it all together
[theCombinedString appendAttributedString: endString];


// now display it in a textView to make sure we have something 
[[junkTextView textStorage] appendAttributedString: theCombinedString];



/// --- works just fine to here --- ///



// the following loads the pastboard, including the added text, but for some reason, leaves out the above attachment 

NSPasteboard *thePboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[thePboard clearContents];

NSAttributedString *theContents = [[NSAttributedString alloc] theCombinedString ];

[thePboard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theContents]];


// pasting into mail or textEdit shows the above before and after text, but not the image.
```

Any ideas?

I've tried using NSData, NSFileWrapper serialized, setting the various pasteboard types, and more. So far, nothing seems to work. If I load the image as TIFF data, it pastes fine, but I need it as an attributed string to insert into a larger string from a file that already has attachments.

*This is my first posting here, so please excuse any formatting errors - I'll learn, and thanks so much for any pointers or help, even if it's RTFM, which I have done but may have mis-understood.*

Answer (score 7):

Finally found the solution, and it was a Wrapper after all.  Here's the code for anyone interested, works with an image read from a file or grabbed from your app:

```
// make a file wrapper
NSFileWrapper* wrapper =[[NSFileWrapper alloc] initRegularFileWithContents:[theImage TIFFRepresentationUsingCompression:NSTIFFCompressionLZW factor:1]];

// -must- have this.  used to save your pasted file in some apps
[wrapper setPreferredFilename:@"yourImage.tiff"];
//
NSAttributedString* imageString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:[[NSTextAttachment alloc] initWithFileWrapper:wrapper]];

// then load pasteboard and paste wherever you wish.  You can get fancier using private 
// pasteboards and custom data types, of course.  This is just a simple example.
```